# how to switch between terminal tabs in VS CODE?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I want to create keyboard shortcut in order to switch between tabs in the terminal window. I tried writing new lines in the json file , but it does not seem to work. I added a picture to explain my self. In the picture there 2 tabs in the terminal the right is green and the right is red . I want to create a shortcut that will switch between the 2 terminal tabs ,just as I did with editor tabs .

[terminal pic with 2 tabs in it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMsm0.jpg)

I tried adding this lines of code to the json file :

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f2",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.nextTab",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f1",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.prevTab",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
```

but it seems it does not work.
edit: I use windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch between the two in the picture with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>rightArrow</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>leftArrow</kbd>. (UpArrow and DownArrow also work)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, to switch terminal you just do ctrl + ~

and to switch back to code editor ctrl + 1

Comment: does not work .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could you use `alt+down`, `alt+right` to switch to the next pane and `alt+up`, `alt+left` to switch to the previous one:

```
{
  "key": "alt+down",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane",
  "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
},
{
  "key": "alt+right",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNextPane",
  "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
},
{
  "key": "alt+up",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPreviousPane",
  "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
},
{
  "key": "alt+left",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPreviousPane",
  "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
}
```